# How to automate an insert in a PostgreSQL database using Python

Tags: pyqgis, postgresql, qgis-plugins

I'm developing a plugin in qgis that makes a selection, identifies the IDs of the selected elements, and wanted it to insert the selected IDs into the PostgreSQL DB.

I have this code to do an insert into the PostgreSQL database from python:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("\
        dbname='postgres'\
        user='postgres'\
        host=''\
        port=''\
        password=''\
");
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO (ID) VALUES ('')")
c.execute("SELECT * FROM ")
conn.commit

records2 = c.fetchall()
import pprint
pprint.pprint(records2)
```

But i wanted the insert to be automated, for exemple, it is not necessary for me to write which IDs are selected, 
but be the plugin to identify and insert the IDs based on the selection i made.

Comment: Can you give a bit more information regarding what the ID format/data type is? Is it also the primary key? If it is a serial/bigserial, then you don't need to specify the id, it will autoincrement. However if the ID is being derived from attributes from your select query and ID is the primary key, you need to consider how to ensure it remains unique, each time you run this script.

Comment: To be honest i do not dominate the databases subject, so do not take it bad if i say something
is not very correct. In my case the ID is evaluated by selected query attributes and are key.
for your life, as always, every time I use the script.
What script is that i can use this case? @LiamG